# Riddle me this: What Am I?

Tags: riddle

I run out.
I am found in the kitchen.
I come in different shapes and sizes,
and you cannot get me in your local supermarket.

**What am I?**

Comment: Hello and welcome to Puzzling SE! A word of advice the title for your puzzle generally shouldn't be the puzzle itself. Instead you normally want to make it be a brief indicator of the type of puzzle it is that will also uniquely identify your puzzle in case people want to find it again later. Have a look at the tour for some more info and get your first badge from this link: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Are you an ex-wife?

Comment: Geez @Chowzen _shots fired_ (but well played).

Comment: @Chowzen - Who says you can't get one at the local supermarket?  Other than that it fits. +1 haha

Answer (score 9):

Your

> Refrigerator

can

> Run out of food, is found in the kitchen, comes in different shapes and sizes (full-sized fridge vs bar fridge), and cannot be purchased in a supermarket.

Comment: Chris Cudmore: Thank you for the kind suggestion, but you'll notice that the grammar of the sentence, which was correct, is now no longer correct due to the edit! Note that the phrase was "Your (answer) can (verb)..." but now it reads "You are a (answer) can (verb)..."

Comment: Close to your answer, but I was thinking of a pantry.

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> Kitchen Bench Space

I run out.

> Running out of bench space is a common thing, especially in smaller kitchens.

I am found in the kitchen.

> Usually the kitchen bench is in the kitchen

I come in different shapes and sizes,

> Nearly every kitchen will have a different layout and amount of bench space

and you cannot get me in your local supermarket.

> I've never seen a supermarket stock benches, though you could argue that certain things available at a supermarket can help you save bench space, increasing it indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> A home cooked meal.

I run out:

> Everyone loves a home cooked meal. Leftovers are the best at midnight.

I am found in the kitchen:

> You may be served in the dining room, but you are born in the kitchen and leftovers are always stored in the fridge

I come int different shapes and sizes:

> Meal for one? Or a Thanksgiving feast for 30?

You cannot get me in your local supermarket:

> Some supermarkets try to have ready made dishes, but they don't come close to a good home cooked meal